# Count animation using SCSS is not working on iPhone

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I'm a CSS newbie trying to set up a simple counter that visually increases or counts a number from e.g. 0 to 100. I used code from css-tricks.com that works on desktop (Chrome), but it's not working on mobile (iOS Safari or iOS Chrome). I wonder if anyone could see why it fails?

The guide I'm following: https://css-tricks.com/animating-number-counters/

Codepen link for the counter I'm struggling with: https://codepen.io/CarterLi/pen/NWNJvPE

The CSS (SCSS) code

```
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

div {
  animation: counter 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  padding: 2rem;
}
div::after {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 100;
  }
}
```

I've read a bit about adding -webkit-, but I'm not sure where it should be added in this example.

I'm also thankful for any other suggestions on achieving something similar. I've also looked into using JavaScript, but I prefer the animation effects using CSS. Thanks!

Comment: Refer to https://caniuse.com/?search=%40property , @property may not be supported on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the @property is not fully supported in all browsers...which might be the reason for this animation not working on iOS devices.

[Src: https://css-tricks.com/animating-number-counters/ ]
[image]

To achieve the "almost identical" effect, you can make use for loop in SCSS:

```
div {
  font: 800 40px system-ui;
  padding: 2rem;
  &::after {
  animation: counter infinite 5s alternate ease-in-out;
  content: "0";
  }
}

@keyframes counter {
  @for $i from 0 through 100 {
    #{$i}% {
      content: "#{$i}";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a code pen demo for the same:
https://codepen.io/iamtheDreamer/pen/jOQQBGm